# How to read output from a process other than StandardOutput and StandardError

Tags: .net, vb.net, command-line

When I run program gpg in the command line without any arguments, I get the following:

```
---->gpg
gpg: Go ahead and type your message...
```

Then the program waits for input. But "gpg: Go ahead and type your message..." is not contained in either the StdOut or StdErr streams which I have asynchronous handlers setup to capture. How is it possible to access and read this?

EDIT: I feel the need to clear up some confusion. It is NOT the case that I want to capture what the user inputs *after* the line "gpg: Go ahead and type your message..." - I can do that fine. Nor am I having any difficulty redirecting any actual output or errors from the program. It's just that when I run the program in cmd with no arguments, the line "gpg: Go ahead and type your message..." appears before accepting input, whereas when I run the process with no arguments through my application it just goes straight to waiting for input without "gpg: Go ahead and type your message..." appearing in either the standard output or standard error streams. In all other ways the program behaves as expected (i.e. everything that is displayed in cmd appears in either StdOut or StdErr) - I am simply curious as to why this is. How is this line being written to the buffer without passing through one of these two streams? And how can it be captured?

Comment: Input is read through the 3rd one, StandardInput.  You can only send input to the program, you cannot read back whatever the user typed in.

Comment: @HansPassant StandardInput (as far as I know) can only be _written_ to, not read - unless of course there is some workaround that isn't a method of .StandardInput.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not trying to read back what the user enters. The line "gpg: Go ahead and type your message..." appears in the command line just before accepting input, but that line does not show up in either the StandardOutput or StandardError streams I am capturing when trying to run the process from my application. i.e. when I transfer all user input, StdOut and StdErr to a textbox, the result is just: --->gpg | [USER INPUT] rather than ---->gpg | gpg: Go ahead and type your message... | [USER INPUT]

Comment: Well, don't be too surprised that a program that handles cryptography doesn't support redirection.  You'll get plenty of hits when you google "gpg output redirection".

Comment: The actual output redirects fine (at least as far as I've tested it) - it's just that one line "gpg: Go ahead and type your message...". After typing the message and closing the input stream the output is redirected fine. And when gpg is run with any arguments, then everything that is displayed in the command line window is captured by either StdOut or StdErr - it's just the one (trivial) line (as far as I can tell) that won't redirect and I'm curious (and a little frustrated) as to why that is.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm running into the same problem when running cmd.exe. The prompts don't show up until actually input something and hit/process Enter.